# How to page a table generated by an ajax call on runtime

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am generating a table depending on the user's selected choice by calling a servlet using AJAX call onchange of dropdown. The table is generating fine, but the problem is I want to page the table as well as it has a lot of rows. I have tried a lot of jquery plugins, but haven't been able to page the table as most plugins want table id which is only generated on ajax call.Please Help...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the paging plugin in the `success` callback for the AJAX request, since at that point the table will exist and you should know the `id` of the table. If you don't know the `id` of the table at that point the easiest solution would be to modify the server-side code to pass that back as part of the response (as a property of a [JSON](http://json.org) object).

If that's not an option then you'll have to traverse the DOM in order to get a reference to the table, then get the `id` from that. I'd need to know the HTML structure of the page to tell you exactly how that would look.

Comment: @user2164574 Excellent, glad it helped. If you found an answer to a question you asked useful you can accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this plugin
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

You can trigger the sorting externally by refering this url
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html

Comment: Use Jquery to trigger the sorting on success of your ajax call